# Example in which parallel execution is faster than sequential execution

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm looking for an example in which parallel execution is faster than sequential execution (in  C++). I tried some things:

quicksort on sorted arrays,

calculation of 1000000 prime numbers,

NxN matrix inversion

But sequential execution is always faster. As you can see I work with two identical threads which execute the code in the `threadWrapper(int threadNo)`

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <ctime>                                                                
#include <thread>                                                               

using namespace std;

void threadWrapper(int threadNo) {                                              

  clock_t start = clock();                                                    

  cout << "thread " << threadNo << ": started" << endl;                       

  // do something crazy                                                                        

  clock_t ends = clock();                                                     

  cout << "thread " << threadNo << ": has finished, elapsed time " << (double)(ends-start)
}

int main() {                                                                       

  cout << "SEQUENTIALLY:" << endl;                                               

  clock_t seq_start = clock();                                                   

  threadWrapper(1);                                                              
  threadWrapper(2);                                                              

  clock_t seq_ends = clock();                                                    

  cout << "sequentially: elapsed time " << (double)(seq_ends-seq_start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC <

  cout << endl << "PARALLEL:" << endl;                                           

  clock_t para_start = clock();                                                  

  thread first(threadWrapper, 1);                                                
  thread second(threadWrapper, 2);                                               

  first.join();                                                                  
  second.join();                                                                 

  clock_t para_ends = clock();                                                   

  cout << "parallel: elapsed time " << (double)(para_ends-para_start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << 

  return 0;                                                                      
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well, writing to output is a blocking operation so that will cause extra delays.

Comment: Take a look on routines which makes CPU to wait for some peripherals respond, i.e. hdd or network connection. Strictly evaluation tasks will always be faster within one thread on single core, which you probably use

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? Yes: do you have any numbers?

Comment: For very long operations, if your threads are actually being executed on different cores, I would definitely expect it to be faster. It's obvious. But there is overhead in threading, so if you don't see any improvement it may just be due to that. Your examples are fairly weak cases for multithreading. As @bigblackdot said, blocking operations absolutely necessitate multithreading.

Comment: For prime numbers up to 1,000,000 (as opposed to 1,000,000 prime numbers), generate primes until 997 ~= sqrt(1,000,000) is reached. Then one thread can search starting at 1001, and another at 501,001 using the common list. Once both threads are done, the lists of primes can be concatenated. To generalize this, the lower number thread would append to the list (with numbers out of range for the higher number thread to check), then start just past the end of the upper range, reversing the roles of the threads (higher becomes lower and vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with threads and parallel processing remember these considerations:

- I/O is a bottleneck.
- Memory is usually a bottleneck.
- Managing threads requires an overhead.

Adding threads may not speed up an application, but they will definitely make it more complex.

**The I/O Bottleneck**
Accessing I/O, whether it be a hard drive, data from a video camera, or sending through Bluetooth, will cause a thread to wait.  If correctly written, the OS will suspend the thread until the I/O is ready.  This will happen on a single threaded program as well.

Unless you program has something to do while waiting for I/O, parallel threads won't help here.  You just cause more work for the RTOS.

**The Memory Bottleneck / contention**
In most PCs and embedded applications that have multiple processor cores, the usually share the memory (external to the chip).  There may be contention when one core wants to access memory at the same time another core accesses memory.  One thread (core) will have to wait for the other to finish (or interweave the requests).  This contention may cause you to loose efficiency that you thought you would gain.  Most processors are transferring data to and from memory, using the shared databus a lot.

The Graphics Processing Unit makes programs more efficient because it has it's own memory.  When you tell the GPU to animate an object, the GPU uses its memory which removes the contention with the CPU's memory.  Thus there is a significant amount of performance gain.

**Overhead of Managing threads**
There is an overhead associated with the creation, maintenance and destruction of threads.  With a single thread or core application, the RTOS can assign it to a CPU and wait for it to end.  Not much extra effort.  With multiple cores, now the RTOS has to switch "threads" between the two cores and monitor the other core for resource requests and contentions in addition to the default core.

A thread should perform enough execution to make the thread creation and maintenance worthwhile.  If the additional thread(s) can offload a lot of activity from the main CPU, they are worthwhile.  For example, a thread that adds two numbers and returns the sum, is too simple and not worthwhile. A thread that reads a file into memory would be worthwhile.

**Summary**
Multiple cores and threads don't magically perform tasks.  They have a creation, operating and destruction overhead.  The rule of thumb is to create additional threads if they can offload work asynchronously from the main cpu and they are used frequently.

Answer (score 6):

From Cpp Reference on `std::clock` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock):

> Returns the approximate processor time used by the process since the beginning of an implementation-defined era related to the program's execution.

The measurement that you are doing is processing time, not wall clock time. Threading will not require *less* cpu (it actually requires a bit more), but you can do more things in parallel, which means that from the point of view of the user it runs *faster*.

I.e. If each `threadWrapper` takes 1s, both counts will point to approximately 2 seconds (sequential vs. parallel), but the whole process will complete in 3 seconds.

Comment: That documentation URL... is a bit misleading.  I was ready to protest that he isn't using `std::chrono`, but that is indeed the doc for `std::clock`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I am not going to go to the page to fix it... I guess I can hide the url here :)

Answer (score 0):

Anything that persistently blows out the TLB or otherwise has to wait on intermittent-to-bursty main memory activity.  (*edit: the closer the duration of the stalls matches the productive intervals between, the more boost parallelism will get.  You might remember this is the math for buffered I/O ... yup.  Main memory is an I/O device these days.